# Destroy calling guarantee in iterators

Tags: delphi, iterator, freepascal

Suppose we have a custom iterator in FreePascal as an object:

```
{$MODE OBJFPC}
....
type TLuaTablesEnumerator = object
private
  {...}
public
  constructor Create( aState : PLua_State; aIndex : Integer );
  destructor Destroy;
  function MoveNext : Boolean;
  function GetEnumerator : TLuaTablesEnumerator;
public
  property Current : TLuaTable read FCurrent;
end;
```

Is there a guarantee that `Destroy` will be always be called? I tried the basic cases and it seems to be so, although there's no mention about it in the documentation.

In particular - is `Destroy` going to be always called, also when:

1. we exit the loop normally
2. we exit from the loop prematurely using `Break` or `Exit`
3. we exit from the loop via a raised Exception

If to any of these questions the answers is "No" -- a follow up question - would it change if the iterator was a class?

Comment: Not an answer, but it looks incorrect because your destructor is missing the override declaration. Usually you want to override the virtual destructor, and not to introduce a new one with the same name. A guess is that the code generated is equivalent to a try/finally block, so is guaranteed the iterator is always freed.

Comment: @jachguate This is `object` rather than `class`

Comment: Adding the "override" is not correct when using `object` instead of `class`

Comment: @Kornel Which mode is the compiler operating in? Does it make a difference to the question?

Comment: Probably not, but I'm using OBJFPC mode.

Comment: Where is `object` allocated? On the stack? In Delphi I'd use a `record` for my enumerator to avoid heap allocation? Is that possible in FPC?

Comment: @David thanks for the correction, I don't use _objects_ since TP7 and I failed to notice it here.

Comment: I guess this [example](http://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop#Using_any_identifiers_instead_of_builtin_MoveNext_and_Current) blesses what you are doing. But I cannot find any documentation. For what it's worth, why do you need a destructor to run?

Comment: @David, The enumerator allocates the returned object - it needs to deallocate it no matter what. objects in FP are basically like records but with more extended syntax. They get allocated on the stack.

Comment: `function GetEnumerator; begin Result := Self; end;`
With tricks like this i'd prefer only use ref-counted interfaces type.
I'd definitely fear `Destroy` called before actual enumeration started.

Comment: Can FPC's objects return different enumerators ? For example `for Cell in DBGrid1 do` and `for Column in DBGrid1 do` and `for Row in DBGrid1 do` ?

Comment: @Arioch - yes, although it would look `for Cell in DBGrid1.Cells' and `for Column in DBGrid1.Columns` - `Cells` and `Columns` would be simple functions returning an iterator.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz hey! that thing Delphi can too (though those things would have been record member, but not big difference). I asked specifically for different elements of same container object! BTW i googled http://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop#Multiple_enumerators_for_one_class and http://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop/ru#.D0.92.D1.8B.D0.B1.D0.BE.D1.80_.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B5.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D0.B4.D0.BB.D1.8F_.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.B7.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F -

Comment: those links show quite different syntaxes... are there some proposals, that were not copied to EngWiki ?

Answer (score 2):

No to all.

Same as in Delphi Destructors are only implicitly called in response to interface reference count going to zero. (though that interface might be in an olevariant).

TP objects are static, and in FPC they additionally respect nested automated types. But destructors need to be explicitly called still

Since none of your questions involve interface use, the answer is **NO**.

Comment: If the answer to this question is no, then the behaviour is different from Delphi. Enumerator objects created in a for/in loop are destroyed. And that must happen in FPC too. In a for/in loop the programmer has no access to the enumerator object and so is in no position to destroy it. Therefore the compile must write out code that destroys it.

Comment: Well, I could still be right it it returns an interface :-) But I assume you checked that is not the case (am not on a FPC/Delphi capable machine atm). For the case of TP Object case of for..in, it is not really recommended to mix TP and Delphi functionality. Afaik TP Objects don't automatically inherit from tobject (which defines a virtual destructor), so in the case above there might not even be a default destructor to call

Comment: I'm also not 100% sure if this declaration is a TP object in Delphi like modes. Make sure you check it. In some modes object() was an alias for normal delphi classes. Again, I'm currently not on a machine where I can easily check things

Comment: Ok, so why *does* it work? I checked both with a log message inside the destructor and with the debugger -- I do not call the Destroy explicitly, yet when exiting the loop it gets called! This only happens in the iterator context of course - I know that without refcount no destructors get called, hence my surprise.

Comment: Probably sb fixed it then. But TP objects issues (specially if they are not really about TP compat) usually last long to fix, which is what I wanted to say. I expect this will only increase because 2.6.0+ supports records with methods. And in general remain undocumented.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz I guess that if Marco doesn't have this information at his fingertips then it must be a dark and dingy corner of fpc. In which case I would steer clear of it. Use either records or classes for your enumerators.